# Php, sort files by date ascending, mark as red text

Tags: php, file, sorting

**Issue**

How can I in PHP list and sort files ascending by date and mark first 3 lines / files (red color)? For example like this.

```
<div class="red">20191010-file.xlsx</div>
<div class="red">20191009-file.xlsx</div>
<div class="red">20191008-file.xlsx</div>
20191005-file.xlsx
20191004-file.xlsx
20191003-file.xlsx
20191002-file.xlsx
20191001-file.xlsx

...
```

**I tried**

```
chdir($path);
  array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', ($files = glob("*.xlsx"))), SORT_DESC, $files);
  $reallyLastModified = reset($files);
  foreach($files as $file){
    $lastModified = date('F d Y, H:i:s',filemtime($file));
    if($file == $reallyLastModified){
      echo'
        <tr>
          <div id="p1" style="display: none;">LINK/'.$file.'</div>
          <td class="file_new"><p style="color:red;">NEWEST FILE</p><a href="LINK/'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$file.'</a>
          <td class="file_new"><button class="button_delete" title="Smazat" type="submit" name="name" value="'.$file.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Opravdu chcete smazat '.$file.'?\')"/></button></td>
        </tr>
      ';
      }
      else{
        echo'
        <tr>
          <div id="p1" style="display: none;">LINK/'.$file.'</div>
          <td><a href="LINK/'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$file.'</a>
          <td><button class="button_delete" title="Smazat" type="submit" name="name" value="'.$file.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Opravdu chcete smazat '.$file.'?\')"/></button></td>
        </tr>
        ';
      }
    }
  }
```

But this is only for 1 file. How can I do that for first 3 files? Or is simplest way, for example via `scandir` to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your code, your array is already sorted by date. You used array_multisort to sort the array already. Your "$files" array is sorted from newest to oldest modify date. If you are going to use the "foreach" loop then you would have to use a counter to keep track of the first 3 elements.

However, if you change your loop to the "for" loop then you won't have to keep track of anything. You basically have 2 "for" loops. The first one prints the first 3 elements while the next one prints the rest. If there is only 1 file. That file will be highlighted red. If there are more than 3 files, the first 3 will be highlighted red while the rest won't be.

```
<?php

array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', ($files = glob("*.xlsx"))), SORT_DESC, $files);
$arrLength = count($files);

for ( $i = 0; $i < ($arrLength > 3? 3 : $arrLength); $i++ ){
    echo'
    <tr>
        <div id="p1" style="display: none;">LINK/'.$files[$i].'</div>
        <td class="file_new"><p style="color:red;">NEWEST FILE</p><a href="LINK/'.$files[$i].'" target="_blank">'.$files[$i].'</a>
        <td class="file_new"><button class="button_delete" title="Smazat" type="submit" name="name" value="'.$files[$i].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Opravdu chcete smazat '.$files[$i].'?\')"/></button></td>
    </tr>
    ';  
}

for ( $i = 3; $i < $arrLength; $i++ ){
    echo'
    <tr>
        <div id="p1" style="display: none;">LINK/'.$files[$i].'</div>
        <td><a href="LINK/'.$files[$i].'" target="_blank">'.$files[$i].'</a>
        <td><button class="button_delete" title="Smazat" type="submit" name="name" value="'.$files[$i].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Opravdu chcete smazat '.$files[$i].'?\')"/></button></td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
```

Comment: won't that break if there are less than 4 files? I would set up a count variable outside the loop and on count <3 turn them red.

Comment: Nope, it won't break. The second loop will not execute if there are fewer than 4 files. For the second loop, $i start at 3 so if $i is not smaller than the amount of index your array has then the loop will not be executed.

Comment: But you'll have an extra <tr> if there are only 2 files.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Sorry about that. I can't believe I missed that. So for the first loop, you compare $i against the length of your array if its length is 3 or less. Else, you compare $i against 3.